# Is it possible to load sourcemaps for cloudflare-served JS files loaded into a page with rocketscript?

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, source-maps

I am transpiling a js file with sourcemaps, pushing it to AWS S3 and then caching it with cloudflare.

I've turned on the rocketscript option to enhance the performance of page loads.

I've purged the cloudflare cache and should have the latest transpiled js file along with the sourcemap file in the cache.

Is it still possible to load source-maps to be able to debug js source, served from cloudflare with rocketscript? Should it work out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

It should work out of the box without purging cache (Rocket Loader isn't a caching feature).